# Replace consonants with previous letter and vowels with next letter in a String

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in C. I'm trying to make a program that changes the vowels with the next letter in the alphabet, and the consonants with the previous letter. I would be happy if you could help me. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void modifyString( char vovels[], char string[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < strlen(vovels); j++){
            if(string[i] == vovels[j]){
                (char)(string[i] += 1);
            } else if((string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z')){
                (char)(string[i]-= 1);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s ",string);
}

int main() {

    char vov[]="aeiou",str[100];

    printf("String is : ");
    gets(str);
    strlwr(str);
    modifyString(vov,str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is ill-defined. What is the expected output if I input "do"?

Comment: @TanveerBadar "cp"

Comment: If I introduce "Daniel", I should get this "cbmjfk"

Comment: See [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/3422102) - always use `fgets()` (or POSIX `getline()`) or loop with `getchar()` or `fgetc()` manually.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "a" is vowel, it must turn into "b"

Comment: Hehe... I snapped to that as soon as I posted the comment -- so I deleted it `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks for the suggestion, but  that doesn't solve my problem (((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not far off. You can just loop over the strings without calling `strlen()`, for example iterating with `for (int i = 0; string[i]; i++)` which will increment `i` until it points to the *nul-terminating* character at the end of `string` which is ASCII `'\0'` and has the value of plain-old `0`. The loop in `str2lower()` (below) does the exact same thing except it iterates with a pointer instead of an index.

Your logic in `modifyString()` looks fine, but you should not cast `(char)` when incrementing the values. There is no need. You can simplify your logic by letting `strchr()` check if the current char is one of the characters in `vowles` with `if (strchr (vowels, string[i]))` eliminating the `j` loop altogether.

It's unclear where `strlwr(str);` is defined, but you can write a simple string to lower easy enough.

Also in my comment, you *never, ever, ever* use `gets()` or use `scanf()` with `"%s"` without using the *field-width* modifier (e.g. `"%99s"`) to prevent a string longer than your array from writing beyond the end of your array creating a buffer-overrun.

If you put that together, you can do something like:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

/** convert string to lowercase.
 *  returns string with all chars converted to lowercase.
 */
char *str2lower (char *str)
{
    if (!str || !*str)    /* check string not NULL or empty */
        return NULL;

    char *p = str;        /* user pointer enabling return of str */

    for (; *p; p++) {     /* loop over each char */
        if ('A' <= *p && *p <= 'Z')   /* if upper case */
            *p ^= ('A' ^ 'a');        /* make lower case */
    }
    
    return str;           /* return modified string */
}

/* modify vowels +1 and consonants -1 */
void modifystr (const char *vowels, char *string)
{
    for (int i = 0; string[i]; i++) {       /* loop over each char */
        if (strchr (vowels, string[i])) {   /* is char in vowels? */
            string[i] += 1;                 /* if so, increment */
        }
        else if ('a' <= string[i] && string[i] <= 'z') {
            string[i] -= 1;                 /* decrement */
        }
    }
}

int main (void) {
  
  const char *vowels = "aeiou";
  char str[MAXC];
  
  fputs ("enter a string : ", stdout);
  
  if (!fgets (str, MAXC, stdin)) {
      puts ("(user canceled input)");
      return 0;
  }
  
  modifystr (vowels, str2lower(str));
  
  printf ("modified string: %s\n", str);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/modifystr
enter a string : My DOG has fLEAS and My Cat has nONE!
modified string: lx cpf gbr ekfbr bmc lx bbs gbr mpmf!
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

---

**Eliminating `strchr()` and Using a Loop**

You can replace `strchr(vowels, string[i])` by adding back your `j` loop and looping over each vowel. You need to keep a flag variable (like `found` and if a vowel is found, set `found = 1`. You want to `break;` the loop as soon as a vowel is found.

After the loop you will test `if (!found && 'a' <= string[i] && string[i] <= 'z')` to know you need to update a consonant value.

Putting it together, you could rewrite `modifystr()` as:

```c
/* modify vowels +1 and consonants -1 */
void modifystr (const char *vowels, char *string)
{
    for (int i = 0; string[i]; i++) {       /* loop over each char */
        int found = 0;                      /* flag tells if vowel found */
        for (int j = 0; vowels[j]; j++) {   /* loop over each vowel */
            if (vowels[j] == string[i]) {   /* if string[i] matches */
                string[i] += 1;             /* increment string[i] */
                found = 1;                  /* set found flag true */
                break;                      /* break vowel loop */
            }
        }
        /* after loop, if vowel !found and [a-z] */
        if (!found && 'a' <= string[i] && string[i] <= 'z') {
            string[i] -= 1;                 /* decrement consonant */
        } 
    }
}
```

It does the same thing, without `strchr()`.

Comment: An extraordinary and explicit solution. I have one more question : how to modify this code so as not to use string processing functions but only array operations ?

Comment: See update to answer:

Comment: Omg, you are great, thank you very much

Comment: Glad it helped. Good luck with your coding! Always compile with full-warnings enabled and do not accept code until it compiles cleanly without warning. Compilers have gotten very good at identifying the exact line and column where problem code is found. You can learn a lot of C just by listening to what your compiler is telling you `:)`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that the inner loop is repeated 5 times (once for each vowel in `vov`, and for every consonant the value is incremented 5 times.

Here is a better way to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

const char *VOWELS = "aeiou";

#define isvowel(chr) strchr(VOWELS,chr)

void modifyString(char *str)
{
    for(int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
        if (isvowel(str[i]))
            str[i]++;
        else if (isalpha(str[i]))
            str[i]--;
    }
    printf("%s\n",str);
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[100];

    printf("Enter a String: ");
    fgets(str,sizeof str,stdin);
    strlwr(str);
    modifyString(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that `strlwr` is not standard C, and `gets` is deprecated.

Comment: Nice touch with the `strchr` macro.